# Does anyone know where is org.springframework.security.acl.basic.AclObjectIdentity class?

Tags: java, spring-security, classnotfoundexception

I can't find a jar in Spring 3.2.X with mentioned class. Does anyone know where is it?

I need it to run jasperserver-api. In documentation they say to use Spring 3.x. It's why I'm looking for this class in spring-3.x libraries.

Comment: That class, with that exact name, does not exist in Spring (Security) 3.

Comment: It is `org.springframework.security.acls.model.ObjectIdentity`. You can get jar file names here: http://repo.spring.io/webapp/archivesearch.html?1